# Python adding integer lists as columns to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

I have 3 lists of integers in format:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
```

I am trying to enter these into a CSV file in the following format, with each item in each list taking a row and each list taking a new column:

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

Currently my code(below) is able to add the first list into the CSV, although i am having trouble adding the second and third lists in the way i wish.

```
with open('Test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    for item in a:
        csv.writer(f).writerow([item])
```

Gives CSV Output:

```
1
2
3
```

If i simply use the following code the b list is added to the same column, i require it to be inserted into the second column:

```
for itemB in b:
        csv.writer(f).writerow([itemB])
```

Gives CSV Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip(a, b, c)` gives you a list of rows: `[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]`

```
with open('Test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for row in zip(a, b, c):
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: To get closer to the OP's output I think you might have to specify the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]

with open('/tmp/test.csv','wb') as out:
    for row in zip(a,b,c):
        csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ').writerow(row)
```

or even:

```
with open('/tmp/test.csv','wb') as out:
    csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ').writerows(zip(a,b,c))
```

Output:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.csv
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: For brevity you could replace your last two lines with ``csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ').writerows(zip(a,b,c))``